# EJB 3 CMT How to rollback first transaction without rollback sub-transactions?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm using an application with EJB and CMT transactions. I have an EJB (let´s call it as EJB1) with a CMT defined as "requires_new" by annotation, like:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

Since there´s is no transaction until now, it creates one. Now, this EJB1 calls another EJB (EJB2). All I found in my researches is the unique way to create another transaction is using a "requires_new" like:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

It work perfectly, the new transaction is created. The problem is about the rollback situations: When EJB2 fails only it´s transaction is rolled back, as expected. When EJB1 fails all of them are rolled back, as expected too but not what I need...

What I need is similar, just this difference: when EJB1 fails it should be rolledback, but I want EJB2 still commited if it not fails.

Did I make me understandable? I don´t want a sub-transaction when it´s parent fails rolled back every one. I want a independent transaction (like a parallel one), for each EJB I invoke from the main EJB.

Comment: Is that possible for you to create one more layer on top of EJB1? I would say you should orchestrate your call on EJB1 and EJB2 in separate transaction from that top layer.

Comment: @Sandip Thanks for you reply. I got what you have in mind, simple and for sure solve my problems and I didn´t think that yet... It will have a great impact on the code I have now. But I still curious if CMT has any solution for this, lol... Once again thanks, I´ll study the impact of implement your ideia while still looking for idieas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transactional attributes you mentioned should work as you expected in your scenario; if the call to EJB2 succeeds it will commit on its own since it's requires_new. In this case, though, if an untreated exception pops up before that EJB2 call, it might not even be invoked giving the impression that everything is being rolled back.

If that's not the case, you can also control the transaction in EJB1 by injecting the EJBContext and calling context.setRollbackOnly(). This will mark the current transaction as to be rolled back when it finishes and it will work as you expect.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your reply. I think you don´t get my problem, or I don´t understand exactaly what you said. What I need is: EJB1 is called, then it calls EJB2 with REQUIRES_NEW transaction. EJB2 return with no exception and it´s transaction is "prepared to commit" waiting just for the EJB1 to commit. But in the case EJB1 fails and rollback it will rollback my EJB2 transaction too, and I don´t want that, I want the EJB2´s transaction still commited. I know my english is confuse, so thanks again by your effort.

Comment: I´m was searching about what you said, and I´m start to thinking my concepts are wrong. Is this right? Actually REQUIRES_NEW will create a complete separeted trasanction, and won´t rollback if the "ancestor" transaction rolls back. is this my mistake? my concepts? Thanks again...

Comment: You're right; when you create a transaction with "Requires new" it will run in its own transactional context and it is independent of who called it. So back in this scenario, your EJB1 would open a new transaction because it's at "Required" (joins an existing transaction or creates a new one if one does not exist). When the code gets to the method call on EJB2, that method call will run in a totally different transaction because of the "Requires new"; this means that if EJB2 rolls back, it won't affect the transaction on EJB1.

Comment: One the key concepts is here is how your EJB method calls join or run into different transactions. In your EJB2 "Requires new" method, if you'd invoke another EJB with "Required" attribute and it rolls back, it would affect the transaction with this third EJB and the EJB2 since it has joined EJB2's transaction.

Comment: Just to confirm, and about the oposite? If EJB1 fails after invoke of EJB2 runs successfully? EJB2 Transaction still commited? right? If it´s true, I´ll open other question on how to make a "save point" on a transaction lol... I just thought thats the way to this hehehehe =\

Comment: If EJB2 is at "Requires new" and it's invoked successfully it will commit; EJB1 will only commit its changes if it completes without any exception. The "Requires New" in EJB2 will make it independent from EJB1's transaction. I'm not sure if you should look for save points in a transaction, perhaps it's just a matter of creating the right transactional attributes and separating your method calls?

Comment: I will think about this... probably you are right about separate my methods... and hope you are right about transaction too lol... =D Really thanks for your all your patience and explain... Abraços

Answer (score 1):

**I can't confirm** your statement:

> It work perfectly, the new transaction is created. The problem is about the rollback situations: When EJB2 fails only it´s transaction is rolled back, as expected. When EJB1 fails all of them are rolled back, as expected too but not what I need...

I had EJB1's method without any annotation (should default to `REQUIRED`, I guess) and EJB2's method annotated with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`.

EJB1 was calling EJB2. In EJB2 I persisted an entity and left the method. Back in EJB1 I caused a rollback by throwing an exception. **In the end EJB2's change had persisted, although EJB1's had certainly been rolled back.**

Additionally, after EJB2 had been left, you already could see the committed change in the database (having paused EJB1's execution with a break point).

Comment: Thanks by your reply, but it was almost a year ago, and I'm not sure what happened that case, not even if I´m wrong on my question assumption. Maybe I was mistaken, really don´t remember... sorry...

Comment: Don't mind, I just wanted to clarify this in case somebody else comes across this site and has the same problem. Indeed that's the reason I came here :-D